# UIDatePicker in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

I have created a UIDatePicker UI, scrollable, but not able to select and display in the UITextField.
Anybody can help me how to do this in Monotouch?

Answer (score 0):

Download the MonoTouch samples [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples) and check the MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop example. It has exactly what you need.

Comment: These examples are for Mono for Android.  I believe this question pertains to MonoTouch.